# Python Multiprocessing -- how to make all processes enter a code block at the same time

Tags: python-multiprocessing

My code looks like this, for each process:

```
def foo():
    while True:
        a = func1()
        func2()
```

and I wish to collect the results of `func1` from different processes and process them in `func2`. Processes may have to enter `func2` together, since `a` varies across iterations and across processes.

Is there any way to synchronize different processes so that they always enter `func2` at the same time?

**More explanation**:

Say `func1` gives out values from number series 1,2,3...
and `func2` is to add the value `a` from every process up. What I hope to achieve:

1. process 1 execute `func1` and gives out `a=1`
2. process 2 execute `func1` and gives out `a=2`
3. process 1 and 2 execute `func2`:1+2=3
4. process 1 execute `func1` and gives out `a=3`
5. process 2 execute `func1` and gives out `a=4`
6. process 1 and 2 execute `func2`:3+4=7

What I actually achieved :(

1. process 1 execute `func1` and gives out `a=1`
2. process 2 execute `func1` and gives out `a=2`
3. process 1 and 2 execute `func2`:1+2=3
4. process 1 execute `func1` and gives out `a=3`
5. process 1 execute `func2`:2+3=5

So maybe they need to enter `func2` at the same time?

Comment: Can you do a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve?

Why would you like to run in the same time?

Comment: @LuizFernandoLobo I edited my post and I hope this helps. I am not a native English speaker, so perhaps I didn't convey my meaning accurately.